# This question popped up

Tags: discussion

There was an interesting question that popped up and it made me wonder - what would be the scope of [Can the Mobile Management facility of Google Apps for Business be used to control certain installations of specific apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64540/can-the-mobile-management-facility-of-google-apps-for-business-be-used-to-contro)

Its referring to corporate usage of enterprise version of Google Apps (is there a such thing?)

*Never thought I'd see this type of question!*

Comment: Running for a train, so no time to leave an answer, but it's a "Mobile Device Management" question. There's a few related ones on the site already (most under the [tag:multiple-devices] tag

Answer (score 5):

I think this kind of question is very close to others we've had about enterprise-style deployment of Android devices in businesses and schools. We don't have the right kind of users on the site to give good answers yet, but if we keep getting these questions, the experts will find us soon enough.